# Ubuntu 22.04's suspend not suspending only locks

Tags: nvidia, suspend, 22.04

As of very recently, my Ubuntu 22.04 (on Dell XPS17 x86_64) does not suspend and only locks and shows the user/pass page. (sudo dmesg -T | grep -20 -i suspend | tail -42) returns nothing and (sudo systemctl suspend) does exactly what I described above.

$ uname -a

Linux 5.15.0-46-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP 2022 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ nvidia-smi

| NVIDIA-SMI 515.65.01    Driver Version: 515.65.01    CUDA Version: 11.7     |